# How to get a better threshold image than Otsu applied to entire image

Tags: python, opencv, image-thresholding

I have tried to apply Otsu's within ROIs of an image to get a better output. My current iteration of code is shown below where I apply Otsu's to 45x45 ROI segments of an image. The output is still not the best, especially when compared to Adaptive Thresholding methods. How can I get a clearer and all around better output? Is there another method for applying Otsu's within ROIs that is recommended?

```
def roiOtsu(image):
    size = 45
    column, row, result = properties(image)
    for i in range(0, column,size):
        for j in range (0, row,size):
            ret,result[i:i+size, j:j+size] = cv2.threshold(image[i:i+size, j:j+size],0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return result
```

Comment: How about adding some test images? Why do you consider the output "not the best"? Also, might want to [read the theory](https://medium.com/@hbyacademic/otsu-thresholding-4337710dc519) behind Otsu's thresholding just to make sure that's the method that will work in your case.

Comment: Otsu threshold is not always appropriate for all images. You might try simple tresholding or adaptive thresholding. Please show your input and output images

Answer (score 1):

Otsu's method works for bimodal images (images whose histograms have two peaks), is your image bimodal?

**Anyway**

By dividing the image and calculating a treshold for each patch you are using Adaptive thresholding. Otsu's treshold instead should be applied to the whole image, thus shouldn't be used like that.

Have you tried simply:

```
otsu_threshold, image_result = cv2.threshold(
    image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU,
)
print("Obtained threshold: ", otsu_threshold)
```

If the result still isn't satisfyng you could turn to adaptive methods but using the right algorithm. You can get some good exmplanation from this other [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2504)

Hope this was usefull for you!